# how to award a bounty without starting one?

Tags: support, bounties

I recently had a specific problem which had a poor visibility. I could find the exact question I needed (and the answer on SO). So I thought of giving some amount of my reputation to that answer, but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Reading the FAQ, I see the only method would be to start a bounty on that question and then award the bounty.

Is there any direct way, I can give away some reputation points to a answer?

Hope, I haven't missed something very basic here, please help me understand how is this doable if possible?

Comment: Have you tried upvoting the answer? It doesn't take away from your reputation, but it gives reputation to that person. If you want to give more reputation, a bounty is the only possible thing to do.

Comment: You need to start a bounty.  One of the options is "Reward Existing Answer".  You won't be able to award the bounty immediately, but you will be able to do it.

Comment: publicizing the question (twitter, blog, fb etc) with positive comments often attracts upvotes for both the question and answer also. You can't be sure what they'll get, but it's a nice thing to do for the people involved and for the site

Comment: @Stijn yes I am aware upvoting a post doesn't take away my reputation. Please read my question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You have just two possibility for increasing the reputation of the guy on a question that is not yours:
- you can upvote the question / answer 
- you can open a bounty and reward it

Actually I don't see any other possibility

As written in comments one of the options while opening a Bounty is "Reward Existing Answer". You won't be able to award the bounty immediately, but I would use this system.